# Why is the handle on the bottom have a hole?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, faces

I was following Andrew Prince's tutorial on how to make coffee cup. I applied my solidify modifier. Everything looked fine. After I was done with the plate I had noticed there was a hole in the bottom of the cup at the handle, showing the bridge between the cup and handle. I have already saved it and do not want to have to make a whole other cup. How did this happen and how can I fix it? [image]

Comment: weird that you used a Solidify for the cup if it had a handle, there must be an inner face, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I was following a tutorial I found on youtube Donuts and coffee by Andrew Prince, https://youtu.be/SBtDix7xGOg

Comment: I am trying to crash coarse my way through blender with youtube tutorials. I just picked it up 4 weeks ago.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=dnMzWSw8" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/dnMzWSw8/)

Comment: yes so make the Subdivision Surface invisible, switch to Edit mode and Face select, and hide some faces around this part, you'll see that it's a bit messy, but you can easily clean that with some delete face and grid fill

Comment: Where can I get a quick reference for grid fill?

Comment: One more question do I hide faces on the inside or the outside of the cup?

Comment: hide the faces where you see the problem with H, it will allow you to see the inner faces that are not supposed to be there, but you can even see that the topology is not good, you have one face where there should be 2

Comment: OMG... I did it. Thank you so much moonboots!!!!! You saved me a half of day of work. I know its silly but I just started and this is my first project!!!! :D